# java servlet http url request

Tags: java, servlets

When I run this code from Java app I get correct response (UTF-8 encoded).

The problem is, when I run it from my servlet, I'm geting:

> "×¤×©×˜×•×ª ×”×™×� ×”×ª×—×›×•×� ×”×ž×•×©×œ×�"
>   ×œ×�×•× ×¨×“×• ×“×™ ×¡×¨ ×¤×™×™×¨×• ×“×” ×•×™× ×¦'×™

Any idea how to fix it?

```
  URL url;
  HttpURLConnection conn;
  BufferedReader rd;
  String line;
  String result = "";
  try {
     url=new URL("http://www.walla.co.il");
      conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String s1="";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((s1 = rd.readLine()) != null) 
                sb.append(s1+NL);
      System.out.println(sb);
     rd.close();
     return sb.toString();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
return "";
```

Comment: If you expect the input to be `utf-8`, you should be passing that as the second argument to `InputStreamReader`'s constructor.

Comment: my really problem is the output trying to login to a webserver and it fail worng username/pass am sort of sure this the same problem i try few things to set the encode to utf 8 but nothing workt  i dont understand why it works fine in java app and not in the servlet this the same class

Comment: As Powerlord said, you are relying on the default encoding. So the same class can behave different on systems with different default encodings. You should always specify the expected encoding and never depend on the default encoding.

Comment: i try seting it in the constructor ,still not working in the servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"

i run this from *.bat file in my tomcat\bin
and it fix the problem seems like i had to set the encode for tomcat/jvm
not 100% sure but it works now :)